# Combining the code of MAX30100 and DS-18B20

Tags: programming, ds18b20

sorry to ask this but I am very very new to Arduino.
My project aims to collect the skin temperature by 18B20 and the heart rate & SPO2 level by MAX30100.
I have tested the codes for the respective sensors and they work fine, but when i am trying to merge these two codes together, only 18B20 works and 30100 isn't delivering any information (Heart rate:0.00bpm / SpO2:0%). Is there a way to combine these two codes? Thank you very much!

Code of 18B20

```
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>

// Data wire is plugged into digital pin 2 on the Arduino
#define ONE_WIRE_BUS 2

// Setup a oneWire instance to communicate with any OneWire device
OneWire oneWire(ONE_WIRE_BUS);  

// Pass oneWire reference to DallasTemperature library
DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);

void setup(void)
{
  sensors.begin();  // Start up the library
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(void)
{ 
  // Send the command to get temperatures
  sensors.requestTemperatures(); 

  //print the temperature in Celsius
  Serial.print("Temperature: ");
  Serial.print(sensors.getTempCByIndex(0));
  Serial.print((char)176);//shows degrees character
  Serial.print("C  |  ");
  
  delay(500);
}
```

Code of 30100

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include "MAX30100_PulseOximeter.h"
 
#define REPORTING_PERIOD_MS     1000
 
PulseOximeter pox;
uint32_t tsLastReport = 0;
 
void onBeatDetected()
{
    Serial.println("Beat!");
}
 
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial.print("Initializing pulse oximeter..");
 
    // Initialize the PulseOximeter instance
    // Failures are generally due to an improper I2C wiring, missing power supply
    // or wrong target chip
    if (!pox.begin()) {
        Serial.println("FAILED");
        for(;;);
    } else {
        Serial.println("SUCCESS");
    }
     pox.setIRLedCurrent(MAX30100_LED_CURR_7_6MA);
 
    // Register a callback for the beat detection
    pox.setOnBeatDetectedCallback(onBeatDetected);
}
 
void loop()
{
    // Make sure to call update as fast as possible
    pox.update();
    if (millis() - tsLastReport > REPORTING_PERIOD_MS) {
        Serial.print("Heart rate:");
        Serial.print(pox.getHeartRate());
        Serial.print("bpm / SpO2:");
        Serial.print(pox.getSpO2());
        Serial.println("%");
 
        tsLastReport = millis();
    }
}
```